# stuck with minimax algorithm - what next? Haskell

Tags: haskell, tree, artificial-intelligence, minimax

I'm writing a basic MiniMax algorithm for a 2 player board game. So far I have a function that evaluates a board and returns a score. I have a function that returns a rose tree of all possible moves (and moves for those moves) etc... to a given depth. I can find the leaves of that tree and give them a value based of my heuristic and my question is what do I do after that?

Do I somehow edit the parent of the leaves and assign the parent node a new value based on the children's value and keep going until I get to the root node?

Am I meant to create a new tree from the leaves up, picking the min / max value until i get to the root node? If so, how does the new tree remember all the moves needed to get to the leaves?

I only want to use imports from the standard library (I don't want to have to download a package). Any suggestions would be great, been struggling with this for a few days. 
Thanks

---

I tried to pick out some parts of my code to give examples but there's just a lot of functions tangled together. If it helps at all here are the type signatures for the main functions and an explanation of what they do:

This function takes in an `Int` (representing `Depth` of tree),  a `Game` (current state of board), list of immediate possible moves and returns a rose tree with each possible move (and moves to those moves) and a score associated with that move. If player is Dark its score is positive, if player is dark its score is negative - each depth in the rose tree is the next players move.

```
roseTreeAtDepthN :: Int-> Game -> [Position] -> [Rose (Position,score)]
```

For example: `treeAtDepthN 2 initialGame [(2,3),(3,2),(4,5),(5,4)]` returns :

```
[Rose ((2,3),4) [Rose ((2,2),-3) [],Rose ((2,4),-3) [],Rose ((4,2),-3) []],
 Rose ((3,2),4) [Rose ((2,2),-3) [],Rose ((2,4),-3) [],Rose ((4,2),-3) []],
 Rose ((4,5),4) [Rose ((3,5),-3) [],Rose ((5,3),-3) [],Rose ((5,5),-3) []],
 Rose ((5,4),4) [Rose ((3,5),-3) [],Rose ((5,3),-3) [],Rose ((5,5),-3) []]]
```

I have another function which allows me to get the leaves of a tree. I use the function that evaluates the game state in `treeAtDepthN` for each move  but I realize that probably isn't necessary and should only be used on the leaves of the tree. I'm not sure if this helps at all.

---

*later edit:*

Not sure what to do next for my minimax algorithm. I have a function that prints all possible moves to a certain depth, I have a heuristic that evaluates those each move, I'm just not sure how I turn it into one function that returns the best move. I only want to use functions given in the Haskell library (Don't want to download any packages ect).

```
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a]
    deriving Show
```

I thought I might be easier to understand if I drew a picture explaining the functions I have. I Have two solutions I can think of which are outlined in the picture, I'm not sure which approach I should go for, if any. :

[image: Imagine]

I guess I want a function that turns the [Rose a] at the top of the picture to the rose a at the bottom of the picture.

Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to offer much guidance without seeing any code. But logically, if you've got everything set up that you describe, you've done all the hard work - all that remains is to write a recursive function which, given a tree, calculates the best move according to your heuristic.

Comment: Please share your attempt together with sample data and expected output.

Comment: @RobinZigmond I edited the post to include a photo. I hope it's easier to understand. Basically need a function that turns the [Rose a ] at the top of the photo to the Rose a at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't actually need to build a tree with updated scores.  You just need to calculate the best move (the one that maximizes the minimum, worst-case score).

So, start with some preliminaries:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

type Position = (Int,Int)
type Score = Int
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a]
```

We can write a function that takes a list of move trees and selects the move (aka `Position`) that results in the maximum of the minimum scores:

```
maximin :: [Rose (Position, Score)] -> (Position, Score)
maximin = maximumBy (comparing snd) . map minscore
```

The helper `minscore` calculates the minimum score for a move tree, assuming best counterplay.

```
minscore :: Rose (Position, Score) -> (Position, Score)
```

If we're at a leaf, our best estimate of the score is the direct heuristic evaluation of the current board, so we just return that position and score:

```
minscore (Rose x []) = x
```

Otherwise, we calculate the score from best counterplay using the opposite of `maximin`, namely `minimax`:

```
minscore (Rose (pos,_) moves)
  = let (_,score) = minimax moves in (pos,score)
```

Note that `minscore` always returns the next move (`pos`) from the root of the tree, but the score will be taken from the root (for leaves) or by further recursive calculation (for nodes).

The full definition of `maximin` and its mirror image `minimax` is:

```
maximin :: [Rose (Position, Score)] -> (Position, Score)
maximin = maximumBy (comparing snd) . map minscore
  where minscore (Rose x []) = x
        minscore (Rose (pos,_) moves)
          = let (_,score) = minimax moves in (pos,score)

minimax :: [Rose (Position, Score)] -> (Position, Score)
minimax = minimumBy (comparing snd) . map maxscore
  where maxscore (Rose x []) = x
        maxscore (Rose (pos,_) moves)
          = let (_,score) = maximin moves in (pos,score)
```

Applied to your pictorial example:

```
example = maximin
  [Rose ((1,1),2) [Rose ((1,2),3) [], Rose ((1,3),-2) [], Rose ((1,4),4) []],
   Rose ((2,2),3) [Rose ((2,3),-7) [], Rose ((2,4),-1) []],
   Rose ((3,3),1) [Rose ((3,4),2) []]]
```

you get:

```
> example
((3,3),2)
```

which looks like what you wanted.

A few notes on performance:

- The minimax algorithm doesn't actually use the heuristic scores of internal nodes, only at the leaves, so you might be better off processing a `[Rose Position]` and only calculating a heuristic score where you need it (when you detect a leaf in `minscore` or `maxscore`).
- [Alpha-beta pruning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha%E2%80%93beta_pruning) is a well-known optimization of the minimax algorithm, and ought to be used in any serious implementation.

Anyway, the full code is:

```
import Data.List
import Data.Ord

type Position = (Int,Int)
type Score = Int
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a]

maximin :: [Rose (Position, Score)] -> (Position, Score)
maximin = maximumBy (comparing snd) . map minscore
  where minscore (Rose x []) = x
        minscore (Rose (pos,_) moves)
          = let (_,score) = minimax moves in (pos,score)

minimax :: [Rose (Position, Score)] -> (Position, Score)
minimax = minimumBy (comparing snd) . map maxscore
  where maxscore (Rose x []) = x
        maxscore (Rose (pos,_) moves)
          = let (_,score) = maximin moves in (pos,score)

example = maximin
  [Rose ((1,1),2) [Rose ((1,2),3) [], Rose ((1,3),-2) [], Rose ((1,4),4) []],
   Rose ((2,2),3) [Rose ((2,3),-7) [], Rose ((2,4),-1) []],
   Rose ((3,3),1) [Rose ((3,4),2) []]]
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up figuring it out but this implementation is a lot cleaner and more efficient.